# Recovering signal from magnitude and phase of FFT

Tags: fft, phase, magnitude

I'm trying to code the basics of an analysis-synthesis system on MATLAB, but I'm getting incorrect results. From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform):

$$
X_k=\lvert X_k\rvert e^{i\angle X_k}
$$

Here's a simple MATLAB code:

```
y = speech(10:10+127);

yfft = fft(y,128);

spec = abs(yfft);
phase = unwrap(angle(yfft));

Y = spec .* exp(sqrt(-1)*phase);

yinv = ifft(Y,128);
```

yet `y` and `yinv` do not match. What's the issue here?

Comment: what's your sample rate? 128 samples worth of DFT surely doesn't sound like a "recognizable" sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running the same code, and it works fine, except for 2 minor points:

1. It's preferable to use `exp(1i*phase)` instead of `exp(sqrt(-1)*phase)`
2. The final result will deviate from the original signal due to rounding noise (typically around `1e-16`). Also, some of this noise will appear in the imaginary part of the result (so, even if `y` was real, `yinv` will be complex, due to the small imaginary component). This will be particularly apparent if you try: `plot(yinv)`, because Matlab will see that `yinv` is complex, and plot it on the real/imag axis